# How to include ejs partials with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am writing some code which checks if a user has logged in. And if a user is logged in, the "my user" section should be different from when that user was not logged in.

So when the logged-in user enters the "my user" page, an if statement checks for if the user has logged in or not, and if the user is logged in, it should include a partial that corresponds to the logged-in state. If the user has not logged in, the if statement should include a different partial.

How do I include partials in a div using JS?

I have tried to use `parentElement.innerHTML = "<%= include userNotLoggedIn.ejs %>` without luck, and I have also tried to manually edit the html file while it runs in the browser using the inspect tool, but it doesn't fetch the template.

It seems like I can't include partials after the main html file has been rendered. Is this the case?

Here is my code:

```
 if(document.getElementById("loginState").innerHTML == " Logg inn") {        
                //Append the correct html template if the user is not logged in
            var includeStr = "<%= include notLoggedIn.ejs %>";
                cont.innerHTML = includeStr;
        } else {
                //Append the desired html template if the user is logged in
            var includeStr = "<%= include userLoggedInMenu.ejs %>";
                cont.innerHTML = includeStr;
        }
```

where `cont` is the container in which the template should be added to

I would expect the partial to be added to the container element, and that my `notLoggedIn.ejs` file is displayed in the html page. This is not the outcome, however.

Please check out the image below: (I can't post images directly into the post)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPFFl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ejs` gets rendered on the server side and gets sent back to the client as HTML. Id don`t think you can add in ejs at the client side.

One possible way to achieve what you are trying would be to set a variable called `currentUser` and the pass it on to the ejs file and in the file you would set a condition like below to conditionally display content.

```js
// Making the logged in user available
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
});
```

```js
<% if(!currentUser) { %>
// If the user is not logged in
<% } else { %>
// If the user is logged in
<% } %>
```

Comment: Yeah, okay that seems like a good solution. I did a less elegant version where I preloaded all the partials into the main html file and kept them in a seperate container, but just set their properties as `display: none; pointer-events: none`. It works, but it isn't exactly elegant..